# OpenLDAP hardware requirements

Tags: openldap

I am new to OpenLDAP and I would like to know what the hardware requirements are for an implementation.

I couldn't find much information, except for this:

RAM: 1GB + 1.5 times the size of the LDIF database of the server
CPU: 500MHZ + 1MHz for any concurrent LDAP operation per second
Add 512MB RAM fpor each CPU core...

Could that be appropriate?

Regards!

Comment: Well that of course depends on your environment. Thousands of queries per second and huge amount of data in LDAP of course requires more than a small office setup with just handful of users. Are you just performing authentications using OpenLDAP or will it be doing something else, too. I bought a car, is it a suitable car for me?

Comment: You are right Janne, I am sorry. Well, at a first step I will be setting up a lab. Anyway, how could I know those parameters you mentioned ? , I mean, like a table that indicates figures depending on those factors.